# OpenRasta CreatedResourceUrl use

Tags: javascript, openrasta

I am sending the following response from server :

```
return new OperationResult.Created { CreatedResourceUrl = getURI(newDuplicateKfEntity), ResponseResource = newDuplicateKfEntity };
```

My question is how can I get this `CreatedResourceUrl` object in my javascript??

Answer (score 0):

Instead of OperationResult.Created return a typed DTO and use a Codec to encode it as Json. After that consuming Json in JavaScript is simple.